# Xamarin Picker not updating after api call

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, picker

I have a xamarin picker that should display a list of countries after getting them from the api (from inside viewmodel), but when I set the itemsource to a List variable the picker doesn't update.

```cs
public Departures(DeparturesViewModel mod)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    model = mod;
    GetCountryData();
}

private async void GetCountryData()
{
    var res= await model.SetCountries();// load api data
    CountryPikcer.IsEnabled = true; 
    CountryPikcer.ItemDisplayBinding = new Binding("Name");//Set the name property as the display property
    CountryPikcer.ItemsSource = model.FilterCountries("");//get loaded List<Country>
}
```

ViewModel:

```cs
private List<Country> countries;


public int CountryId
{
    get { return countryId; }
    set { SetProperty(ref countryId, value); }
}

public DeparturesViewModel()
{
    api = new ApiCaller();
    countries = new List<Country>();
}

public async Task<bool> SetCountries()
{
    countries = await api.GetAll<List<Country>>("Countries");
    return true;
}

public List<Country> FilterCountries (string text)
{
    if (text == "")
        return countries;
    List<Country> filtered = countries.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(text)).ToList();
    return filtered;
}
```

Inside the debugger the ItemsSource property is getting populated but the picker is not [image: observe]

Comment: Post your viewmodel it's more important how you handle item source.

Comment: @Adlorem Added the viewmodel

Comment: where is the `FilterCountries` method you are using as your ItemSource?

Comment: @Jason its inside the viewmodel it just returns the List<Country> property I will add it anyway

Comment: are you sure that method is returning data?  And does `Country` contain a public property "Name"?

Comment: @Jason yes the function returns data ( as  seen in the picture) and the Country object has  a     public string Name { get; set; }

Comment: If you remove assigning 'CountryPikcer.ItemDisplayBinding', do you see a default '.ToString()' output inside a picker? Still trying to understand whether the problem is in an item binding or in `ItemsSource`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion your problem is in viewmodel.  You are using async call that means that all your controls got rendered before data from async call is available. In this case your viewmodel should implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Then for example:

```
public List<Country> Countries
{
    {
      set { countries = value; PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Countries))); }
      get { return countries; }    
    }
}
```

To ensure that controls data is refreshing properly.